# Transfer files from one google compute engine instance to another?

Tags: ssh, scp, google-compute-engine, pull, gcutil

I'm trying to copy files from one GCE instance to another. Instead of using google cloud storage with `gsutil` (which sometimes hangs for me), I'd like to try using `gcutil pull`.

I'm trying to do:

```
gcutil pull someInstance /some/file/path/here .
```

It works however the command asks me to enter a new passphrase (for ssh I assume). Since I'm running this from a script is there a way to default this passphrase to empty?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to use passwordless SSH:

http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html

I have used gcutil push to send files from master node to slave nodes (hadoop/spark) with it.